# avoid refresh page and required field doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, required

I want to submit a form disabling refresh and I want the ajax to do the POST request to avoid refreshing the page.

Here I got something structure like this but my required tag doesn't work

```
<form id="test">
     <input type="text" name="title" required/>
</form>

<button id="submitForm">Save</button>
```

Then I make javascript like this:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#test").submit();
     console.log('success');
});
```

why is my form refreshing and not validating the required field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are bypassing all stuff you get for free.

Here is how

1. Use the submit event
2. Move the submit button to the form

```js
$('#test').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // $.post(url.....)
  console.log('success');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" name="title" required/>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

3. or use form="test" on the tag

```js
$('#test').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // $.post(url.....)
  console.log('success');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" name="title" required/>
</form>
<button type="submit" form="test">Save</button>
```

If you are planning to add the form dynamically, you need to delegate

```js
$("#container").on("submit", ".dynForm", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // $.post(url.....)
  console.log('success', this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <form id="test1" class="dynForm">
    <input type="text" name="title" required/>
  </form>
  <form id="test2" class="dynForm">
    <input type="text" name="title" required/>
  </form>
  <form id="test3" class="dynForm">
    <input type="text" name="title" required/>
  </form>
</div>


<button type="submit" form="test1">Save 1</button>
<button type="submit" form="test2">Save 2</button>
<button type="submit" form="test3">Save 3</button>
```

Comment: i want my button outside the form since I am creating dynamic forms for it

Comment: can i dynamically add the form="test" using javascript ?

Comment: Depends on how you are planning to do it. If you dynamically add a form, you need to delegate the submit event to the container that wraps it/them

Comment: i have this situation. I am dynamically changing the name of my form for reusability methods like adding and editing. Can I dynamically add that tag?

Comment: See my update on what I thought you meant.
If you use a class on the form, you can change the name all you want on my 3rd example